# How to check wired ethernet is connected or not in mac programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am using `[[CWInterface interface] interfacestate]` to check airport is on/off. I need similar code to check ethernet adapter is connected or not.

Comment: You can use IOKit for this, but I don't have a concrete example.  Here's an Apple sample to get the ethernet MAC, however: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000698-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: If you need to check whether you're connected to the internet you can use Reachability.

Comment: I have used Reachability but it will show 'Wifi is present' for ethernet connected to cable.